# How to jump and rotate an image in android?

Tags: android, image, android-animation

I have an image in image view of my activity. There is button also in my activity. i     want that when i press button image should be jump and rotate and will replace by another image. Actually  i want to implement coin Toss application ?how can i achieve this . any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is for my android application

Answer (score 3):

With `ObjectAnimator` and setting `KeyFrame` it can be achived, which was introduced in API 11.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AnimationSet with animation listeners like:

```
AnimationSet aset= new AnimationSet();
aset.add(jumAnimation);
aset.add(flipAnimation1);
aset.add(flipAnimation2);
```

with flipAnimation1  rotate the view  from 0 degrees to 90 degrees and change the image

then start the second animation and do the rest of the rotation.

```
flipAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //change the image
                                    //start flipAnimation2

            }
        });

});

imageView.startAnimation(aset);
```

Dont forget to set animation attributes like: duration,fillAfter.